# Local DNS lookup always fails first time

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, windows-10

On a very small number of Windows 10 machines at my work we have an issue where lookup of local domain names always fail to be resolved, but only for the first request.

The following is the output from a command prompt, a number of lookups were made one after the other, with no other commands in between.

```
C:\Users\Me>nslookup mail2
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.50.199

*** UnKnown can't find mail2: Server failed

C:\Users\Me>nslookup mail2
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.50.199

Name:    mail2.mydomain.local
Address:  192.168.3.27


C:\Users\Me>nslookup backup
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.50.199

*** UnKnown can't find backup: Server failed

C:\Users\Me>nslookup backup
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.50.199

Name:    backup.mydomain.local
Address:  192.168.3.23


C:\Users\Me>nslookup elrond
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.50.199

*** UnKnown can't find elrond: Server failed

C:\Users\Me>nslookup elrond
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.50.199

Name:    elrond.mydomain.local
Address:  10.0.0.59
```

The following is an IP config just so you can see the network setup.

```
C:\Users\Me>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : XPS13-2
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : mydomain.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mydomain.local

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1820A 802.11ac
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-DF-BF-30-12-B1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34ea:a41a:612c:d401%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.219(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 19 January 2017 08:28:58
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 27 January 2017 08:28:59
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.199
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 91545535
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-34-C3-F9-74-DF-BF-30-12-B1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.199
                                       80.64.54.19
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.199
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

DNS Server is a Windows Server 2008 (Standard) machine, which is also the DC/AD server.

Comment: Why do you have a public DNS server in the ip configuration? Remove that from all machines, including the DC if it's configured there, and try again. Run nslookup in debug mode and post the output of your test after you've made this change.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is likely the DNS Server 80.64.54.19 you gave your clients. Remove that from your clients, as you have a proper DNS server, that should handle all the request.
Why every second request actually fails, is probably because you firewall does not allow DNS query to the outside, so the client run into an timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a DNS reverse zone? Add one for 192.168.50. and add PTR record for your DNS server name.